# How can I convert a MySQL database into an older version?

Tags: mysql, database

How can I convert a MySQL database into an older version MySQL 5.1.48 - > 5.1.46?

Answer (score 1):

you can use NAVICATs, navicat for mysql the best tool available in the market. Very simple and quick.

first you have to download the trail version. Its enough to get this done. connect the navicat with the database with newer version then you have to export the content as CSV format, as the second step you have to import the csv file to the older version of mysql by connecting it with navicat,

http://www.navicat.com/en/download/download.html 
if you cant get it work with the trail try to get an original copy.
If you have any doubts regarding this then plz feel free to contact me, I will help you

Answer (score 0):

Safest way: use mysqldump to dump on 5.1.48 and load on 5.1.46.
If you only use MyISAM, you can copy the contents of your /data directory.

Might I ask why downgrading?

Comment: I may have no choice but to downgrade several customer databases since our current hosting company starts to create more trouble (index tables accidentally deleted, latency did skyrocket from 1 to almost 10 seconds and websites start to time out.) However, most new hosts that I hope can provide adequate service did not update to the MySQL database version we use currently. To transfer and get the pages up-and-running again, I have to (reluctantly) downgrade the database.

Answer (score 0):

Just export the database using `mysqldump` and that will give you an SQL file. You can then import that file into your other database server.